# How to add X and Y point coordinates in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am trying to make a ggplot, how can I add the x and y coordinates for the points ? I tried this code, but it does not work :

```
d4<-Restriangle[1:(n-1),5]
xaxis=c(1:(n-1))
yaxis=Restriangle[1:(n-1),4]
data=data.frame(xaxis,yaxis)
library(ggplot2)
res=ggplot(df, aes(x = d, y = d4)) +  
# Set up canvas with outcome variable on y-axis
geom_point(data=data,size=4, shape=19,color = "blue"),aes(x = xaxis, y 
 = yaxis) )  
# Plot the actual points
res
```

When doing this I get this

[image: output]

How can I add X-Y points coordinates ?

```
>Restriangle 
        1          2           3           4          5         6         
7
1  -897.75585 -412.69207   0.6328851    4.276630 -55.581006 -32.54413 
-84.15410
2 -1126.80146 -177.45009 -96.0334938   -4.558513 -48.247435 -78.89057  
29.46455
3  -402.33108 -101.71760  48.3551429 -149.761948  21.155187  50.29719  
50.74081
4   -88.04207   19.12321 -25.5603718   55.228526  81.502399  49.54745   
0.00000
5   219.95450   65.39756 -28.5352641   39.075518  -8.099494   0.00000   
0.00000
6   427.28240  142.97238   1.0954190   61.520149   0.000000   0.00000   
0.00000
7   669.78983  217.68299  98.3532236    0.000000   0.000000   0.00000   
0.00000
8   850.60581  322.69272   0.0000000    0.000000   0.000000   0.00000   
0.00000
9  1194.20921    0.00000   0.0000000    0.000000   0.000000   0.00000   
0.00000
      8     9
1 -63.06562 0
2  63.88373 0
3   0.00000 0
4   0.00000 0
5   0.00000 0
6   0.00000 0
7   0.00000 0
8   0.00000 0
9   0.00000 0
```

Comment: What are you expecting as output? Do you mean add text of the coordinates? It's easier for folks to help if you include your data

Comment: you should provide a reproducible example.

Comment: This still isn't making a ton of sense (and you haven't told us what `n` is), but keep in mind that `ggplot` expects a single, long-shaped dataframe. Getting your data in the proper shape is probably where you want to start

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `geom_text` which you can read about: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for something like geom_labels ?

```
x <- c(1,3,4,6,9)
y <- x^2
coords = paste(x,y,sep=",")

df = data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point(col="blue")+
  geom_label(aes(x+.5,y+0.5,label=coords))
```

[image]